# Magento Print Packingslips (Pre-shipped)

Tags: php, magento, pdf

We have an issue with the Print Packing slips (pre-shipped) on our Magento 1.9.2 when we enable content delivery network from a provider, it dosn't load the pictures on the generated PDF. When it's without CDN it loads the pictures without issues.

When the media are configured on `{{secure_base_url}}media/` it works.
When the media is configured on `https:// or http://cdn.domain.tld/media` don't works.

As far we understand the issue is in the line 17 of Shipment.php

```
$imageLocation = substr($imagePath,strlen(Mage::getBaseUrl()));
```

Can you please advice how we can load the product pictures on the PDF when the CDN is enabled?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can refer below link and it will be help you.

Above example is related to INVOICE but you can implement in your packageslip functionality so you can just download the example and make necessary changes as per image display.

http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-pdf-invoice-with-product-images-extension/

Thanks..!

Comment: The extension is already installed to the magento and configured for pre-Printpacking slips. The issue is that it doesn't loads images when CDN is configured on the media source. It loads without issues when Magento default media source are configured.
for some reason it don't recognise the image location

`$imagePath = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($image, 'image')
->resize($width);
$imageLocation = substr($imagePath,strlen(Mage::getBaseUrl()));
$image = Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($imageLocation);
//Draw image to PDF
$page->drawImage($image, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2);`